# "In the right combination" vs "with the right combination"?

Tags: grammar

I just realized that both seems to mean the same thing. However, I am not sure if this is something that's context-dependent or not. What do you think?

For example:

> I pressed and used the buttons at the right time and in the right
>   combination.
>
> I pressed and used the buttons at the right time and with the right
>   combination.

Comment: Improvement-- change "in the right time" to "at the right time". "At" is the correct preposition to use.

Comment: Further to the comment by @DonB., I read the example sentences as referring to a rhythm game, for which "in time" (meaning "to a particular rhythm or beat") would be correct. If you didn't mean this, then "at the right time" is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question! I've never thought about this before.

This might depend on the individual and the dialect, so I will only be answering for myself and Australian English.

**In** a combination is used to describe a series of actions (for example, pressing buttons) being done in a particular order. The actions themselves are the combination.

> I pressed the buttons in the right combination.

**With** a combination is used to describe an action (for example, opening a lock) that needs to *use* a combination (a particular sequence). The action is not part of the combination.

> I opened the lock with the right combination.

So in your question, **"in the right combination" is correct.**

Comment: I think these are slightly different senses of the word "combination"; the former is a synonym for "order," but the latter is a synonym for "code."

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon: You could make that argument, but you could equally say that a "combination" in the sense of code is a specific *order* of numbers/buttons/whatever. (Which is, I guess, the origin of the "code" sense.) And "with a combination" could be used with other, non-"code" senses of the word ("with the right combination of flavours", for example).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *I pressed and used the buttons in combination with right time and right combination*. If you'd like to use *with the right combination*  I think you should add *of sth* after combination, i.e. *with the right combination of sth* Please refer to [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76954/difference-between-combination-of-and-combination-between)